# Error when sending a transaction to Open Zeppelin Defender

Tags: openzeppelin, signature, meta-transactions, eip712, defender

I am getting the following error from Open Zeppelin Defender:

```
signature missing v and recoveryParam
```

This is my code:

```
const config = require("../config/config");
const ethers = require('ethers');
const MinimalForwarder = require("../util/abis/MinimalForwarder.json");
const GameEvents = require("../util/abis/GameEvents.json");
const networkRpcURL = config.web3.networkRpcUrl;
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(networkRpcURL);
const { signTypedMessage } = require('eth-sig-util');

const EIP712Domain = [
  { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'version', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'chainId', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'verifyingContract', type: 'address' }
];

const ForwardRequest = [
  { name: 'from', type: 'address' },
  { name: 'to', type: 'address' },
  { name: 'value', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'gas', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'nonce', type: 'uint256' },
  { name: 'data', type: 'bytes' },
];

const getMetaTxTypeData = (chainId, verifyingContract) => {
  return {
    types: {
      EIP712Domain,
      ForwardRequest,
    },
    domain: {
      name: 'MinimalForwarder',
      version: '0.0.1',
      chainId,
      verifyingContract,
    },
    primaryType: 'ForwardRequest',
  }
};

const createInstance = (address, abi) => {
  return new ethers.Contract(address, abi, provider);
}

const getSigner = (i) => {

  // Use the mnemonic to create an HDNode instance
  const account = ethers.utils.HDNode.fromMnemonic(config.web3.mnemonic).derivePath("m/44'/60'/0'/0/" + i);
  const signer = new ethers.Wallet(account, provider);

  return signer;

};

const sendMetaTx = async (iterator, userAddress, sessionId, sessionType) => {

  const url = config.web3.webhookUrl;
  if (!url) throw new Error(`Missing relayer url`);

  const forwarder = createInstance(config.web3.minimalForwarder, MinimalForwarder.abi);
  const gameEvents = createInstance(config.web3.gameEvents, GameEvents.abi);
  const signer = await getSigner(iterator);
  const from = await signer.getAddress();
  const data = gameEvents.interface.encodeFunctionData('startGameSession', [userAddress, sessionId, sessionType]);
  const to = gameEvents.address;
  const request = await signMetaTxRequest(signer, signer.provider, forwarder, { to, from, data });

  return await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(request),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  });

}

const signMetaTxRequest = async (walletPk, signer, forwarder, input) => {
  const request = await buildRequest(signer, input);
  const toSign = await buildTypedData(forwarder, request);
  const signature = signTypedData(walletPk, signer, input.from, toSign);
  return { type: 'forward', forwarderAddress: forwarder.address, signature, request };
}

const buildRequest = async (provider, input) => {
  let nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(input.from);
  return { value: 0, gas: 1e6, nonce, ...input };
}

const buildTypedData = async (forwarder, request) => {
  const chainId = await forwarder.provider.getNetwork().then((n) => n.chainId);
  const typeData = getMetaTxTypeData(chainId, forwarder.address);
  return { ...typeData, message: request };
}

const signTypedData = (originalSigner, signer, from, data) => {
  // If signer is a private key, use it to sign
  if (typeof(signer) === 'string') {
    const privateKey = Buffer.from(signer.replace(/^0x/, ''), 'hex');
    return signTypedMessage(privateKey, { data });
  } else {
    const newTypes = {
      ForwardRequest: data.types.ForwardRequest
    }
    return originalSigner._signTypedData(data.domain, newTypes, data.message);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in this function:

```
const buildRequest = async (provider, input) => {
  let nonce = await provider.getTransactionCount(input.from);
  return { value: 0, gas: 1e6, nonce, ...input };
}
```

Instead of getting the nonce of the sender of the wallet signing the transaction, you have to get the nonce of the `MinimalForwarder` smart contract ON BEHALF of the wallet signing the transaction, like this:

```
const buildRequest = async (forwarder, input) => {
  const nonce = await forwarder.getNonce(input.from);
  return { value: 0, gas: 1e6, nonce, ...input };
}
```